# How to connect boto with fakes3

Tags: amazon-s3, integration-testing, boto

I'm wondering how I connect boto to fakes3 for integration testing.

I'm currently running fakes3 like so:

```
fakes3 -r fakes3 -p 4567
```

and attempting to connect to s3 and creating a bucket in ipython like this:

```
s3conn = S3Connection(access_key_id, secret_access_key, port=4567, host='localhost')
bucket = s3conn.create_bucket('test')
```

This just hangs. Can someone give me an example o connecting to fakes3 from boto?

Answer (score 6):

According to this (https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3/blob/master/test/botocmd.py) from the fakes3 tests, you probably want something like this:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, OrdinaryCallingFormat

s3conn = S3Connection(access_key_id, secret_access_key, is_secure=False, port=4567, host='localhost', calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
```

Comment: Actually, you have a few typo and calling_format must be called like this `s3conn = S3Connection(access_key_id, secret_access_key, is_secure=False, port=4567, host='localhost', calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())`

Answer (score 0):

this happen to me in a mac and I just realized that fakes3 didn't have permission to create files. So I ran sudo fakes3 -r /mnt/fakes3_root -p 4567 & and create_bucket and get_all_buckets worked fine

Comment: which access key and secret you used for `fakes3`

Comment: FakeS3 doesn't care what credentials you give it. However I've noticed that when you don't specify any credentials, Boto will try to get credentials from the Amazon instance metadata service and fail outside of EC2. Specifying bogus credentials is one way to prevent that.